# Puncture resistant tires

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, tire, performance-tracking

The the default tires from my scott aspect 30 (Schwalbe Black Jack, 26 x 2.1, 50TPI) are peaty worn by know and i need to buy new ones.

My main complain is the punctures made by vegetation every day I ride, the next day I have to change the tube because of a small hole on the front tire mainly...

I'm inclined to buy this configuration

front: Mountain King by continental 26 x 2.2
back: Race King by continental 26 x 2.2

Am I on the right direction? any other recommendation? 
does my weight (79 kg/174 pounds) has any influence on my choice?

Comment: Note that any decent Kevlar-belted tire will reduce your punctures 4-10x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continental makes a version of the [Mountain King](http://www.conti-online.com/generator/www/de/en/continental/bicycle/themes/mtb/cc_marathon/MountainKing22/MountainKing22_en.html) (Mountain King 2.2 Protection) with a higher TPI and their [ProTection](http://www.conti-online.com/generator/www/de/en/continental/bicycle/general/innovation/Protection_en.html) anti-puncture system.  I would recommend spending the extra cash on the Mountain King's with this feature.

Alternatively, you could pick up some [Tuffy Liners](http://www.mrtuffy.com/) to add a layer of protection to your existing tires.

Comment: +1 for Mountain Kings with Protection. -1 for Tuffy Liners.

Comment: I though that 2.2 was the thickness not the version am i right? if yes 2.2 is better that 2.1 thickness right

Comment: Sorry, that was just copy/paste. Just make sure it's the mountain king "Protection" version.  I think they make a version of the mountain king without the "Protection", which is probably less expensive, but lacking the extra flat resistance.

Comment: @zenbike what's wrong with Tuffy Liners? I'm asking 'cause I know nothing about it

Comment: They are heavy, and while they work well in the short term, they dry out and get brittle over time. Eventually, after around six months, they will get sharp enough to cause you flats.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here:

http://www.conti-online.com/generator/www/de/en/continental/bicycle/general/innovation/Protection_en.html

...you are going to have an excellent tire. These tight-fabric protection (kevlar or aramid, I guess) work great (at least are working great in my Marathon XR).

For XC and off-road, I think the tight fabric might be preferred over the thick-inner-rubber protection (a la Schwalbe Marathon Plus) due to performance issues (weight and rigidity, mostly).

Another option would be to use anti-puncture tape (Mr.Tuff, Sttones) between the tire and the tube. On the road, these have served me very well (after I finally gave up being skeptical - suffered so long in vain...). In the other hand, on off-road, where pressures are lower and tire deformation is higher, perhaps the built-in protection is a better choice.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was manly for For XC and off-road... Abraço